# bash for loop for given array only accounts for one file out of two files in array

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, grep, dcmtk

I have an array of two files from the `find` command:

```
[ogino@chead SIEMENS]$ DCM_FILES=($(find . -type f))

[ogino@chead SIEMENS]$ echo ${DCM_FILES[@]}
./107939/107939/DICOM/0020_20071002_104554.150005 ./100013/100013/DICOM/0002_20130723_100423.117500
```

I have then constructed a `for` loop in order to dump information in the files (via `dcmdump` of the dcmtk Toolbox):

```
[ogino@chead SIEMENS]$ for dcm in "${DCM_FILES[@]}"
do
  sd=$(dcmdump ${dcm} | grep "(0008,1030)"); 
done
```

However, it seems like it is only reading one DICOM file, as displayed in my output:

```
[ogino@chead SIEMENS]$ echo ${sd[0]}
(0008,1030) LO [RESEARCH^THOMPSON_SCHILL] # 24, 1 Unknown Tag & Data

[ogino@chead SIEMENS]$ echo ${sd[1]}

# I get a blank line for the second instance of my echo testing

[ogino@chead SIEMENS]$ echo ${sd[@]}
(0008,1030) LO [RESEARCH^THOMPSON_SCHILL] # 24, 1 Unknown Tag & Data
```

I tried initiating a blank array for `sd` before the loop, that didn't work (`sd=( )`), and surprisingly, indexing with `dcm` also didn't seem to pick up the second file `${sd[1]}`...

```
[ogino@chead SIEMENS]$ echo ${dcm[0]}
./100013/100013/DICOM/0002_20130723_100423.117500
[ogino@chead SIEMENS]$ echo ${dcm[1]}

[ogino@chead SIEMENS]$ echo ${dcm[@]}
./100013/100013/DICOM/0002_20130723_100423.117500
```

Removing the variable assignment for the `sd` variable seems to remove the error, except, I need to store this particular output somewhere with an array, which is why I set the `dcmdump` command to `sd` in the first place.

```
[ogino@chead SIEMENS]$ for dcm in "${DCM_FILES[@]}"; do dcmdump ${dcm} | grep "(0008,1030)"; done
W: no data dictionary loaded, check environment variable: DCMDICTPATH
(0008,1030) LO [MRI BRAIN/MRHD]                         #  14, 1 Unknown Tag & Data
W: no data dictionary loaded, check environment variable: DCMDICTPATH
(0008,1030) LO [RESEARCH^THOMPSON_SCHILL]               #  24, 1 Unknown Tag & Data
```

Googling around seems to hint to me that there may be an issue with `grep`, but it's not so clear to me at the moment.

**Is there a modification I need to make in my loop to make sure I can store both instances into an array? Any help to point me in the right direction to produce the output above with the second instance of `grep`**

Comment: you're running `sd=$(dcmdump ...)` two separate times, and you're not saving the output from the previous cycle. Prove this to yourself by removing the `sd=$()` part and just let the `dcmdump .. | ...` cmd run by itself to see what output your loop is generating. `sd+=...` might work but I don't have time to test. Good luck.

Comment: Keeping the output from `find` in a variable is superfluous anyway unless you subsequently want to join up the file names with their respective results.

Comment: If have three comments: 1) dcmdump supports multiple input files, so there might be no need for the for loop. 2) dcmdump also has a search function using option --search. 3) The warning message indicates that the DICOM data dictionary has no been loaded; this should be fixed. Reading the documentation of the tool might be helpful: https://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmdump.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about iterating over the indexes of your `DCM_FILES` array instead of the values, since you want the indexes to match in your new array anyway?

```
DCM_FILES=($(find . -type f))
for idx in $(seq ${#DCM_FILES[@]}) ; do
  sd[idx]=$(dcmdump ${DCM_FILES[idx]} | grep "(0008,1030)")
done
echo "${sd[@]}"
```